# How to print the all li items text of dropdown using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How I print the all `li` items text using selenium `webdriver`.
Here I want to some type of single line code that print all `li` items text like

- Jackets,
- protective etc. May by using for loop

  ```
  <div class="dropdown  change_right">
   <ul>            
      <li>
          <a class="" title="Jackets" href="/collections/jackets">Jackets</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a title="Jackets protective" href="/collections/jackets/jackets-protective" class="sub-link"> protective</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
          <a title="casual leather" href="/collections/jackets/casual-leather" class="sub-link">casual leather</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="" title="T-shirts &amp; shirts " href="/collections/t-shirts-shirts">T-shirts &amp; shirts </a>
      </li>
      <li> 
          <a title="shirts" href="/collections/t-shirts-shirts/shirts" class="sub-link">shirts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a title="crew-neck" href="/collections/t-shirts-shirts/crew-neck" class="sub-link">crew-neck</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a title="polo tshirts" href="/collections/t-shirts-shirts/polo-tshirts" class="sub-link">polo tshirts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="" title="Trousers" href="/collections/trousers">Trousers</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a title="Trousers Protective" href="/collections/trousers/trousers-protective" class="sub-link"> Protective</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a simple `findElements()`. With the help of `xpath` to grab the collection of `elements` and a simple iterate through the collection and print the value with the help of `getText()`which returns the string value of the element.

```
List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dropdown')]//a"));
for ( WebElement element: allText) { 
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

*Note: untested code. You may need to make sure click and open the list happens before executing this code and some wait might also be necessary as well*

Comment: You can take the whole class attribute value or partial of it anything like `class='foo foo2'` you can use  `//*[contains(@class,'foo2')]//a` or `//*[contains(@class,'foo')]//a`. Let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: well this code is right. But my menu dropdown items are hidden, items are visible when dropdown parent menu items hover by mouse icon. 
Please do something for this

Comment: Try `Action builder`. It's a workaround of hover over issue..`By byXpath = By.xpath ("xpath for the element to hover over")
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(byXpath)); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();`